# Limit classes to be analyzed by Findbugs in maven

Tags: maven, findbugs

How can I limit the classes to be analyzed for some packages only.
In a module, I don't want findbugs for Maven to be run for some packages. How can I exclude them. Is there any way to specify the packges to be eliminated by Findbugs of Maven

Answer (score 3):

Please refer - http://mojo.codehaus.org/findbugs-maven-plugin/usage.html

Use `mvn site` and not mvn findbugs:findbugs

You need to use include exclude filter files under configuration tag or onlyAnalyze.

```
<reporting>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.2</version>
    <configuration>
      <excludeFilterFile>src/main/resources/findbugs-exclude.xml</excludeFilterFile>
      <includeFilterFile>src/main/resources/findbugs-include.xml</includeFilterFile>
      <onlyAnalyze>com.packagename.*</onlyAnalyze>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Sample filter file

```
<FindBugsFilter>
<Match>
    <Package name="~com\.ly\..*"/>
</Match>
```

Comment: I wrote the exclude.xml file but still it didn't skipped the analysis of those packages.
 My current dir :  A
 Folder hierrarchy:  A/src/main/com/ly/om/sn
 
 Excelude.xml file 
 `code`    <FindBugsFilter>
 <Match>
 <Package name="~.com\.ly\.om\.sn\.*" />
 </Match>
 </FindBugsFilter>
 
 What is incorrect here ?

Comment: How can we check if our filter file is been picked up when I run "mvn site" . As I don't see in report that the packages are been excluded which are been mentioned in exclude-filter file.

Comment: I verified it by adding and removing a package with known findbugs error.

Comment: Okay. Then it means my filter file is not been picked up. Because I see the error which are been raised from package been specified in exclude file :|

Comment: We have filter file checked in at src/main/resources and refer to it in the <excludeFilterFile> . Also, you can try playing around with <inherited>false</inherited> . Note: http://kohsuke.org/2011/08/23/my-epic-battle-with-findbugs-maven-plugin-and-how-i-utterly-lost/

Comment: I updated filter file and added in excludeFilterFile tag. Tried to execute the command by        "$FINDBUGS_HOME/bin/findbugs -textui -exclude /view/xyz/findbugs-exclude.xml app/"                                                     But what I can see is it isnt picking up the file as it is not ignoring the package common.                                         Added the filter file as                                             <FindBugsFilter>
<Match>
  <Package name="~com\.sn\.common\.*" />
</Match>
</FindBugsFilter>